# Get error when I push element onto vector

Tags: c++, class, vector, types

I get a `is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed` error with below code when I want to add the element to the vector with `container.push_back(tmp);`, why is this?
My code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
class A {
    public:
    A(){}
    ~A(){}
};
class my_t {
    private:
        bool busy;
        bool alive;
        std::mutex bmtx;
        std::mutex amtx;
    public:
        my_t(){std::lock_guard<std::mutex>lock(bmtx);busy=false;}
        ~my_t(){}
        A* conn; 
        void take(void) {std::lock_guard<std::mutex>lock(bmtx);busy=true; }
        void give(void) {std::lock_guard<std::mutex>lock(bmtx);busy=false; }
        bool busy_get(void) {return busy;}
        void set_online(void){ std::lock_guard<std::mutex>lock(amtx); alive=true; }
        void set_OFFLINE(void) {std::lock_guard<std::mutex>lock(amtx); alive=false; }
        bool alive_get(void) {return alive;}

};

class app {
    private:
        std::vector<my_t> container;
    public: 
        app();
        ~app();
};
app::app() {
    my_t tmp;
    tmp.conn = new A();
    if (tmp.conn)
        tmp.set_online();
    container.push_back(tmp);


}
int main(void) {}
```

or on Coliru: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11625c77383df80c

Comment: When you push into the `container`, you try to **copy** a `my_t` object. This would invoke the (default, compiler-provided) copy constructor, but this can't exist because it would copy all the members, and [`std::mutex` has a `delete`d copy constructor.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/mutex).

Comment: Please extract a [mcve].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt To be honest I haven't tried to compile it, but it looks like it will compile and exhibit the issue. It's not strictly minimal, but it's not too huge either, only a few extra functions, which are one-liners.

Comment: Not being a MCVE, it makes your question off-topic here. There are good reasons for that, please follow the provided link!

Comment: Sidenote: having `A* conn;` in the `my_t` class suggests you should keep an eye out for the [Rules of Three and Five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). to ensure things are copied correctly once you get the `mutex`  problem sorted out.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the provided example is much minimized already. I wasn't EXACTLY sure what in my program caused the issue & didn't want to omit anything! In order to get the right kind of help from you guys!I'll do better going forward though! Thanks to all involved!

Comment: "I wasn't EXACTLY sure what in my program caused the issue" -- that's why you are expected to extract a MCVE before asking here.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have a vector of your `my_t` objects, because the `my_t` class contains `std::mutex`es:

```
 std::mutex bmtx;
 std::mutex amtx;
```

Mutexes [have a deleted copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/mutex). There's no such thing as copy-constructing a mutex.

Since your `my_t` class also does not have a copy constructor, this automatically deletes `my_t`'s copy constructor as well.

`std::vector`'s value class must have, at the very least, [a copy constructor and an assign operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Template_parameters). This is because a vector must be able to reallocate its contents, in order to accomodate its growth. This means that the elements in the vector must be copyable/assignable.

If you explicitly implement a copy constructor and an assignment operator for your `my_t` class, you'll be able to make a vector out of them. But then you will need to figure out what it means to copy-construct, and assign, to your `my_t` class...

The most you can do, with your class as is, is to have a vector of pointers to `my_t` instances. Perhaps using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```
container.push_back(tmp);
```

you try to **copy** a `my_t` object. This would invoke the (default, compiler-provided) copy constructor, but this can't exist. It can't exist because it would copy all the members one-by-one, and [`std::mutex` has a `delete`d copy constructor.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/mutex).

It doesn't really make sense for a mutex to be copy-able. They don't have [value semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_semantics), and they only make sense when exist alongside an actual value.

So create your own copy constructor for `my_t`, which copies all the members that it can, and just default constructs the others.

You almost certainly also want to [**deep copy**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184710/1171191) the `conn` member, and make it a [`std::unique_ptr<A>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) as well, to make sure it gets `delete`d properly when the object gets destructed.